# Code::Blocks 10.05 and Environmentmental Variables

Tags: environment-variables, codeblocks

I'm probably missing something *really* obvious, but I don't have the **Environmental Variables** dialog shown in [Configuring environmental variables](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html). I've been through **Settings -> Environment...** (and other submenus from **Settings**) and its just missing.

OpenSSL FIPS Capable is particular about having `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC` set to embed the module's fingerprint. I even tried running the following as a prebuild step with no joy (the `echo`'s are empty):

```
Running project pre-build steps
export CC=`find /usr/local/ssl -name fipsld`
export FIPSLD_CC=`find /usr/bin -name g++`
echo $CC
echo $FIPSLD_CC
```

I'm working on Debian 7.3 (x64) fully patched, if it matters. Code::Blocks was installed from Debian's repos. OpenSSL was custom built and installed in `/usr/local/ssl`.

Where does one set environmental variables in Code::Blocks 10.05?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Environment Variables Editor is an optional plugin. Debian packages can be found at [Package: codeblocks-contrib (10.05-2.1)](http://packages.debian.org/stable/codeblocks-contrib).

To install it you need to install package `codeblocks-contrib` as well as `codeblocks`:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib
```

Close and restart Code::Blocks, if it is running. The dialog you looking for will then appear in **Settings** -> **Environment**

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm surprised environmental variables aren't part of the base installation.